# How to convert a word to a Unique Code in Excel using Formula without using VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say, I got 2 words `A1:ddC, A2:DDC`

I want to convert these 2 words into a unique code so that so that i can do the Case Sensitive Vlookup.

So i tried, `=Code(A1)` & it returned 100, but if i tried `=Code("dady")` then it also returns 100. It is cos  `=Code()` only pic the first char of the word.

I want to convert a word to a Unique Code (could be ASCII code or any form of unique code).

So how to do that without using VBA?

Comment: What is the max length of your string?

Comment: it could be 255 chars like a sentence

Comment: Then you will need VBA for this. In fact there is one question in SO which gives you the VBA code on how to do this.

Comment: @SiddharthRout It seems Sean's answer accomplishes this task without VBA.

Comment: @user2140261: Yup but it failed for one scenario. Check this out http://wikisend.com/download/456180/1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***WARNING: *** This is not a solution to the titled question 
         "How to convert a word to a Unique Code in Excel using Formula without using VBA?" but instead is a solution to what I believe is the underling problem as the original question states "so that i can do the Case Sensitive Vlookup." this is a solution acomplishing a Case Sensitive Vlookup, without the need to convert the values before doing so.

An alternative to converting all the values then doing a look up on the converted values, you could use the `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions in an array entered formula and directly look up the values:

```
=INDEX(A1:A14,MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A1:A14,"ddC"),0))
```

This will return the value in `A1:A14`, at the same index of an exact (case-sensitive) match in `A1:A14` to `ddC` you can VERY easily modify this into a look up of other columns.

***Explanation:***

Start with getting an array of all exact matches in your look up list to your look up value:

So if I enter this formula:

```
=EXACT(A1:A14,"ddC")
```

[image]

Then go into the formula bar and press <kbd>F9</kbd> it will show me an array of true false values, relating to each cell in the range `A1:A14` that are an Exact match to my expression "ddC":

[image]

now if we take this Boolean Array, and use the `Match` function to return the relative position of `True` in the array.

```
=MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A1:A14,"ddC"),0)
```

[image]

*But remember we need to enter this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> because we need the `EXACT(A1:A14,"ddC")` portion of the formula to be returned as an array.*

Now that we have the position of the `True` in the array, in this case `6` we can use that to retrieve the  corresponding value in any column, as long as it is relational and that same size. So if we want to return the value of the exact match (although relatively useless in this situation, but will continue for demonstration) in the original look up column we just wrap the last formula up in an `Index` function:

```
=INDEX(A1:A14,MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A1:A14,"ddC"),0))
```

[image]

*But remember we need to enter this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> because we need the `EXACT(A1:A14,"ddC")` portion of the formula to be returned as an array.*

Now we can apply that same concept to a larger range for more useful look up function:

[image]

*But remember we need to enter this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> because we need the `EXACT(A1:A14,"ddC")` portion of the formula to be returned as an array.*

Now notice in this last step I offered 2 formulas:

```
=INDEX(A1:B14,MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A1:A14,D2),0),2)
```

And

```
=INDEX(B1:B14,MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A1:A14,D2),0))
```

The first returns the value in the range `A1:B14` in the Second column at the position of the exact match in `A1:A14` to the value in `D2` (in this case "dady")

The second returns the value in the range `B1:B14` at the position of the exact match in `A1:A14` to the value in `D2` (in this case "dady")

Hopefully someone else can add more input but as far as I know the second might be better performing, as it has a smaller index range, and doesn't require going to the specified column, it is also shorter.

While the first to me is much easier to read, to some (more of a preference I think) because you know that your looking at a look up table that spans 2 columns and that you are returning the value in the second column.

***Notes: *** I am note sure if this solution will be better in practice then converting the original values in the first place, seeing as how converting all the values once, then hard coding the converted values will require no additional formula or calculation (if formulas are afterwards replaced with values) once finished, while this method will recalculate, and also is array entered. But I feel in the case the asker is doing a single look up against a **changing** look up list (one that constantly requires all values are converted at all times using array formula) this option does allow you to remove the formula per word, with one single formula
all in all I hope this solves your original problem,

Cheers!!

Answer (score 5):

As this is a hash, it would be possible for some strings to end up with the same value, but it would be unlikely.
Note that the row function uses 1:255 to generate a list of numbers from 1 to 255 - change this number if your strings end up longer.

```
=A1&SUMPRODUCT(IF(IFERROR(CODE(MID(A1,ROW($1:$255),1)),0)>96,1,0),POWER(2,ROW($1:$255)))
```

This has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> - you will see `{}` around the formula if you have successfully done that.

This will produce a decimal representation of the upper and lower case letters, and this is then appended to the word itself - this will guarantee uniqueness, as the only way to have a word and number match is to have the same word and case, which means it was a duplicate in the first place.

With this, `ddC` = ddC & 1*2 + 1*4 + 0*8 = **ddC6**
`DDC` = DDC & 0*2 + 0*4 + 0*6 = **DDC0**
`ddC` (ddC with a space after it) = ddc & 1*2 + 1*4 + 1*8 + 0*16 = **ddC 6**

Comment: your solution is great but the number is not unique. "chorioallantois", "conventionalism", "synergistically", all return the same number 13012
Can u modify ur formula so that it can make a unique number for any case sensitive word?

Comment: @MinhHai, try the new version - the values returned for the examples you gave are now 7306846, 7181938, and 7442442

Comment: majors, emptor, emboss, marmot all return 14238

Comment: To make it unique, I created a bit pattern to indicate upper/lower case, converted that binary to decimal, and appended it onto the original word - This will mean that your lookup will have to look for word and number, but now it will actually be unique and case sensitive.

Comment: u got a great solution anyway. I sure I can use ur solution in other situation. Again, Thank you very much. 1 Vote up for you.

Answer (score 0):

if all your strings like the one you pointed above try something like this:

```
= CONCATENATE(Code(A1) , Code(Mid(A1,2,1)) , Code(Mid(A1,3,1)))
```

Comment: I haven't tried this on excel if you had any problem tell me so I can fix it.

Comment: do capital letters occurs only on the first letter?

Answer (score 0):

In order to account for capital letters you're going to end up with a VERY long formula, especially if you have long word entries.  Without VBA I would approach it this way and set up the formula once to allow for the biggest word you anticipate, and then copy it around as needed.

Formula (to expand):

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(EXACT(A1,UPPER(A1))=TRUE,"b","s")&CODE(A1),IF(EXACT(A1,UPPER(A1))=TRUE,"b","s")&CODE(MID(A1,2,1)),IF(EXACT(A1,UPPER(A1))=TRUE,"b","s")&CODE(MID(A1,3,1)), . . . )
```

You can substitue the "b" and "s" with whatever you like.  I was just using those for a case check for capital versus lowercase letters (b=big, s=small) and building that into your unique code.

In order to expand this, add additional cases to account for the length of the words you are using by adding this snippet JUST inside the last parenthesis and modifying the "3" in the MID() function to account for a word length of "4", "5", "6", etc.:

```
IF(EXACT(A1,UPPER(A1))=TRUE,"b","s")&CODE(MID(A1,3,1))
```

Painful, yes, but it should work.

Cheers.